# Dynamic select option using Ajax jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I am using Ajax jQuery to get select data with id "pSelId" and "pVim" from my Flask server (please see the HTML code below). This is working fine independently.

Now I have to take decision based on selected option in "pSelId" and return option data in select field "pVim", for which I have to get the value of "#p_name" on my Flask server from the selected value in select field "pSelId" to take this decision. Currently I am assigning static value for p_name='p15' on server side.

I have no idea how to send the value of selected option in

Server side code:

```
@app.route('/listpopvim', methods=['POST','GET'])
def listpopvim():
    #p_name=request.form['pName'];
    p_name='p15'
    p_dict1 = []
    for p in load_p:
       p_dict2={
         'pop': p['fq_name'][1]
        }
       #pop_dict1.append(pop_dict2)

    return json.dumps(p_dict1)
```

HTML / jQuery:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4">
     <h6> P Name </h6>
     <select id="pSelId" name="pName"  class="form-control"> </option> </select>
     </div>

     <div class="col-xs-4">
     <h6> VIM </h6>
     <select id="pVim" name="pVim" class="form-control"> </select>
     </div>
</div>


<script>
getdata()
function getdata(){
              $.ajax({
                        url : '/listpv',
                        type : 'POST',
                        success: function(data){
                                var pretrun = JSON.parse(data);
                                console.log(data)
$( "select" ).change( displayVals );
        var options = "";
         for (var i = 0; i < pretrun.length; i++) {
           if (pretrun[i].pop){
                options += "<option>" + pretrun[i].pop + "</option>";
                      }
                } 
        $("#pSelId").html(options);
                        },
                        error: function(error){
                                console.log(error);
                        }
                });

}

function displayVals() {
        var singleValues = $( "#pSelId" ).val();
        console.log(singleValues) 
}
$( "#pSelId" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();

</script>
```

Comment: Server Side Code:

@app.route('/listpopvim', methods=['POST','GET'])
def listpopvim():
    #p_name=request.form['pName'];
    p_name='p15'
    p_dict1 = []
    for p in load_p:
       p_dict2={
         'pop': p['fq_name'][1]
        }
       #pop_dict1.append(pop_dict2)
       
    return json.dumps(p_dict1)

Comment: Please `edit` your question to include the server sided code, adding it as a comment is quite difficult to read.

Comment: Can't really help much on the python part, but since you already know how to use ajax, why can't you just ajax the `p_name` data back to the flask server?

Answer (score 0):

I think all that you're missing here is the data field in your post request. You'll have to mess around a little bit with what you actually want in the data field because I'm not entirely sure that I understood exactly what you're looking for there, but [this site](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) should help with that.

Python:

```
@app.route('/listpopvim', methods=['POST','GET'])
def listpopvim():
p_name=request.form['pName'];
p_dict1 = []
for p in load_p:
    p_dict2={
        'pop': p['fq_name'][1]
    }
   #pop_dict1.append(pop_dict2)

return json.dumps(p_dict1)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4">
 <h6> P Name </h6>
 <select id="pSelId" name="pName"  class="form-control"> </option> </select>
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-4">
 <h6> VIM </h6>
 <select id="pVim" name="pVim" class="form-control"> </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
getdata()
function getdata(){
    $.ajax({
        url : '/listpv',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {pName : $("pSelId").val()},
        success: function(data){
            var pretrun = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            $( "select" ).change( displayVals );
            var options = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < pretrun.length; i++) {
                if (pretrun[i].pop){
                    options += "<option>" + pretrun[i].pop + "</option>";
                }
            } 
            $("#pSelId").html(options);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
function displayVals() {
    var singleValues = $( "#pSelId" ).val();
    console.log(singleValues) 
}
$( "#pSelId" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply.
I did some modifications and was able to send data to server however i am not able to retrieve using request.form['pName'];
however i can see the data using below code
    ss=request.form
    print ss

another problem is this data is an ImmutableMultiDict, not sure why.
this is the output of print ss on my server console:

> > > ImmutableMultiDict([('pName', u'pop15')])

Here is the modified code:

#### i get data for select1 from this function and result of which will be fwd to another function name displayVals on change event. second function will then populates my select2 field.

#### Function to get data for Select1

```
                     function getpop(){
                          $.ajax({
                                url : '/listpopvim',
                                type : 'GET',
                                success: function(data){
                                     var pop = JSON.parse(data);
                                     console.log(data)
                                    var options = "";
                                    for (var i = 0; i < pop.length; i++) {
                                            if (pop[i].pop){
                                                    options += "<option>" + pop[i].pop + "</option>";
                                                    }
                                            } 
                                            $("#popSelId").html(options);
                                    $( "select" ).change( displayVals );
                                  },
                                  error: function(error){
                                        console.log(error);
                                    }
                            });

            }
```

#### Function to get data for Select2

```
                    displayVals();
                    function displayVals() {
                            $.ajax({
                                    url: "/listpopvim",
                                    data: {pName: $( "#popSelId" ).val()},
                                    ContentType : 'application/json',
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    //data: JSON.stringify(singleValues),
                                    type:"POST",
                                    success : function(response) {
                                            //console.log(response)
                                            },
                                    error: function() {
                                            alert('Error occured');
                                            }
                                    });
                    }
```